# Importing Data to Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a csv-file with data I want to import into Matlab. Since it is a mix of date and numbers I use:

```
data = textscan (fid,'%s%s%n%n%n%n%n',819500,'headerlines',1,'delimiter',',');
```

Unfortunately, the data in column 3-7 has 5 digits and I only get 4 which is wrong, like 
1.1234 instead of 1.12345.

How can I solve this?
What is wrong?

Comment: Do you really just get four or is this the [command line output](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/format-output-in-command-window.html) which may be truncated?

Comment: 4 thats surprises me too ...

Comment: Have you tried other [formats for the import](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html#inputarg_formatSpec)?

Comment: NO, but will try right away. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Matlab often truncates the display of numbers to four decimal places, which is what may be happening.  To check this, try forcing the formatting to five decimal places using `fprintf`:

```
>>> myNum = 1.24028;
>>> fprintf("%.5f", myNum)

        1.24028
```

Or by changing the formatting:

```
>>> myNum = 1.24028;
>>> format long
>>> myNum

    myNum = 

    1.2402800000
```